# About Spring Cloud GateWay throwing java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

`I use：
Spring Cloud starter gateway 3.1.2
reactor netty 1.0.18
netty 4.1.76.Final

**SCG Exception:**

```
2023-12-27 18:17:22.163 \[my-gateway,,\] \[reactor-http-nio-3\] WARN  reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect-\[295\] - \[fc08b3e5-1, L:/192.168.1.51:41704 - R:/192.168.1.51:8198\] The connection observed an error, the request cannot be retried as the headers/body were sent
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:378)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2023-12-27 18:17:22.165 \[my-gateway,,\] \[reactor-http-nio-3\] WARN  com.azt.gateway.handler.GlobalExceptionHandler-\[54\] - Error Spring Cloud Gateway : /my-server/api/contractType/queryUserInfo Connection reset by peer
```

---

I've tried configuring SCG as well as Netty, but to no avail in the end

This exception is probably caused by making a page request for the first time, then waiting for a few minutes, and then requesting SCG again.

Has anyone solved this problem? Please tell me, thank you very much

I tried configuring SCG and Netty

I hope this problem can be solved completely`